# What is meaning of resistance are of same order?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

In meter bridge we know that, bridge is most sensitive when the resistance of all four resistor are of same order. But what is meant by the resistance of the same order? And why in that case meter bridge is more sensitive?

Comment: That is not entirely correct. The sensitivity actually increases if we make one branch with lower resistance than the other. The two resistors in the same branch should be roughly identical, though, so that the midpoint voltages are roughly half the total voltage on the bridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order in this case means order of magnitude. If you're familiar with that term from math then you know what it means for decimal numbers. Two resisters are the same order when the number representing their impedance is of the same order. E.g., 5 ohm and 3 ohm, or 5k ohm and 3k ohm. And yes resisters of the same order make a wheatstone bridge more sensitive.

Comment: I got about the order but why the wheatstone bridge is more sensitive it there is of same order than the of different order?

Comment: The bridge is two sets of series resisters in parallel with each other. Since you add the two resistance on each leg to determine the current, then factor the current into the equation to calculate the voltage drop across one of those resisters,(simple voltage dividers), you get more significant digits of precision if the resisters are the same order than if one is an order of magnitude larger or smaller. Does that make sense?